# SVG fill inside path with no intersections

Tags: svg, fill, svg.js

I'm trying to fill the following path and while I expected it to be filled inside the stroke line I get the following shape (black fill):

[image]

I've tried changing `fill-rule` from `nonzero` to `evenodd` but with the exact same result, what should I do?

```html
<svg id="svg-container" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
      <path d="M12.112500563968936 -80.49999994829511L12.042182152685129 -82.22343949593682L11.831473217997551 -83.94682609775359L11.514855642847493 -85.6247322359464L11.128207005438131 -87.30258542831425L10.670952607720444 -88.93490521123317L10.143626097882809 -90.52211515130273L9.545981176761362 -92.06410935687299L8.877771545192232 -93.60610356244325L8.139489801503156 -95.01186816044131L7.295545716515463 -96.37209934899047L6.838578667822286 -97.00702568167824L6.3463087389749475 -97.59678922569168L5.818982229137315 -98.14101936025617L5.256393889006159 -98.63971608537176L4.658748967884712 -99.00255382368974L3.9904982864549403 -99.3198581525588L2.689628202634715 -99.6826958908768L1.3537425876848381 -99.95483743107152L0.017528573849803664 -100.00000021974586L-1.3183980909607182 -99.95483743107152L-2.654571054935106 -99.6826958908768L-3.9907850687701405 -99.3198581525588L-4.623445521021239 -99.00255382368974L-5.221336741306553 -98.63971608537176L-5.783925081437705 -98.14101936025617L-6.31125159127534 -97.59678922569168L-6.803521520122677 -97.00702568167824L-7.2605296186764985 -96.37209934899047L-8.10443265380355 -95.01186816044131L-8.87805832750743 -93.60610356244325L-9.545980610052048 -92.06410935687299L-10.143625531173495 -90.52211515130273L-10.67123939003564 -88.93490521123317L-11.128206438728816 -87.30258542831425L-11.51485507613818 -85.6247322359464L-11.796169771134078 -83.94682609775359L-12.007166054846163 -82.22343949593682L-12.112499997259626 -80.49999994829511M-12.112499982336715 30.499999485030372C-12.04536024551652 33.631911350749505 -11.566121434420666 35.815474903680865 -10.542819238747384 37.48436543988575C-7.486224840924649 42.4741625233618 -4.332682978296873 46.72232422699756 -0.9603581801688108 49.61208665697819A3.139072091761344 9.151898708905092 0 0 0 0.0004346053615336132 49.998513282651516H0.0004346053615336132A3.139072091761344 9.151898708905092 0 0 0 0.961227390891878 49.61208665697819C4.332684002767934 46.721480500740626 7.485936469978384 42.4741625233618 10.542820263218431 37.48436543988575C11.5658330634744 35.814631177423934 12.04536126998758 33.631911350749505 12.112501006807776 30.499999485030372M-12.1125 27.5A-760.2727435307559 -760.2727435307559 0 0 0 -12.1125 -77.5M12.1125 27.5A760.2727435307559 760.2727435307559 0 0 1 12.1125 -77.5M-12.1125 -77.5C-12.165129099635367 -78.25 -12.112500190734863 -79.75 -12.112500190734863 -80.5M12.1125 -77.5C12.165129099635367 -78.25 12.112500190734863 -79.75 12.112500190734863 -80.5M-12.1125 27.5C-12.165129099635367 28.25 -12.112500190734863 29.75 -12.112500190734863 30.5M12.1125 27.5C12.165129099635367 28.25 12.11250114440918 29.75 12.11250114440918 30.5 " fill="blue" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="red" transform="matrix(0,1,1,0,150,50)"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's the way you are drawing your path. Every time you are using the `M` command you are moving to a different point and you are breaking the path. It's as if you would lift the pencil from the paper and begin to draw from an other point. You have to draw the path "without lifting your pencil from the paper"

Comment: @enxaneta you should make that an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Fuzzyma advised me, I'm making my comment an answer:

It's the way you are drawing your path. Every time you are using the `M` command you are moving to a different point and you are breaking the path. It's as if you would lift the pencil from the paper and begin to draw from an other point. You have to draw the path "without lifting your pencil from the paper".

Comment: As you suggested, changing the way I draw my path did the trick